# Get interior message from array

Tags: php

So I retrieve a failure message with a failed credit card charge by Stripe like so:

```
echo $response['failure_message'];
```

This echoes out:

```
string(185) "{
  "error": {
    "message": "The 'exp_month' parameter should be an integer (instead, is MM).",
    "type": "card_error",
    "param": "exp_month",
    "code": "invalid_number"
   }
}
```

How do I obtain just the `message` from this string?

I have tried:

```
echo $response['failure_message']['message'];
```

But it echoe'd the same thing. I am wanting to just echo out the message.

Comment: You need to use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: try this: echo $response['failure_message']['error']['message'];

Comment: Are you really getting that output from `echo`, not `var_dump`?

Answer (score 1):

by using [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn that payload from json to a php array.

```
$message = json_decode($response['failure_message']);

echo $message['error']['message']
```

this returns "The 'exp_month' parameter should be an integer (instead, is MM)."

Answer (score 1):

```
$ar=json_decode($response['failure_message']);

echo $ar['error']['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's returning a JSON string, not a multidimensional array. You need to decode the JSON string.

Try using [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) like this:

```
$result = json_decode($response['failure_message'])
echo $result['error']['message']; //Should return just the message string.
```